# Can this diagonal matrix be similar to it's negation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, jordan-normal-form

Suppose I have a diagonal matrix such as
$$ A:=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},
$$ 
Is there a way to find an invertible matrix P, such that: $-A = P^{-1} A P $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The existence of such a matrix $P$ would imply that $-A$ is [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to $A$. In particular, this would imply that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{trace}{trace}\trace(A)=\trace(-A)
$$
which is of course impossible since $\trace(A)=1$ and $\trace(-A)=-1$.

Comment: Ah yes, good insight using the trace.  Thank you.